# Упаковка .py в .exe

Tags: python, exe, pygame

Допустим у меня есть некоторый файл .py . В данном файле используются некоторые картинки(они находятся в той же папке, что и .py ). Также используются библиотеки pygame и time. Как это все упаковать в один .exe файл?

Comment: Смотрите в сторону: pyinstaller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В командной строке установите pyinstaller

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

В командной строке перейдите в папку, где находится ваша программа.
Создайте экзешник

```
pyinstaller --onefile
```

В конце строки допишите имя главного скрипта.

Comment: https://datatofish.com/executable-pyinstaller/

Comment: Да в том то и дело. Я всегда им и пользовался. А теперь (После обновы), у меня ошибка создания процесса. Ни pyinstaller ни auto-py-to-exe не робит.